# Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Tags: asp.net

```
public class users
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class IDaccesscontrol
{
    public static List<users> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        List<users> listEmployees = new List<users>();

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["User_KarlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select from user_karl", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                users users = new users();
                users.id = rdr["id"].ToString();
                users.username = rdr["username"].ToString();
                users.password = rdr["password"].ToString();
                users.email = rdr["email"].ToString();
                users.country = rdr["country"].ToString();

                listEmployees.Add(users);
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return listEmployees;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try `select * from user_karl`.

You simply have a syntax error in the SQL statement itself. C# can't pick that up at compile time so you get a runtime exception.

if you can't find these sort of syntax errors, sometimes it can help to copy/paste the SQL statement to SQL Server Management Studio and see it it tells you there. To get the exact statement sent to the server by your app, use SQL Profiler (Tools menu in SQL Server Management Studio).

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is **Select * from user_karl**.In the above code you missed up the star symbol.It retrieve the whole data in the table **"user_karl"**

Change this line in your code :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from user_karl", con);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code have some errors, not only sql-query. Change your code to the following:

```
public class users
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string username { get; set; }
public string password { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
}

public class IDaccesscontrol
{
public static List<users> GetAllEmployees()
{
    List<users> listEmployees = new List<users>();

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["User_KarlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from user_karl", con); //when selecting something from a database, you have to appoint exactly what you want to eject
//otherwise if will occur an error as you had. * means we want to eject all columns from the table
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            users users = new users();
            users.id = rdr["id"].ToString();
            users.username = rdr["username"].ToString();
            users.password = rdr["password"].ToString();
            users.email = rdr["email"].ToString();
            users.country = rdr["country"].ToString();

            listEmployees.Add(users);
            //con.Close(); you are in the while loop, so you can't close connection until you will not finish your work with data
        }
            con.Close(); //working with your reader has been finished, so we can close connection
    }

    return listEmployees;
}
```

}

Comment: When you provide an answer, you should explain *what* your code does differently and *why*.